# Technology and status symbols that predate language

Tags: technology, language, prehistory

I remember distinctly reading about peoples and cultures - in, I believe, the Caucasus - that used to knap large flakes of flint into spearheads and would use them (instead of actual tools) as status symbols of how well they could hunt; the most important part of this being that this pre-dates language.

For starters, could anyone tell me of the culture I'm thinking of? And for second, does anyone know of any technologies that pre-date language?

Comment: sounds silly. An excessively large spear head is far less suitable for its purpose than one just the right size.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like just one person's theory.

There is really no consensus on [when humans acquired language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language#Origin), but most do seem to think that it was at the least part of the package of being an anatomically modern human (Homo Sapiens), so it is at least 100,000 years old. Thus any finds that predate language are probably not human (as we tend to think of it), but rather one of our ancestors or a sibling branch of [genus Homo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo).

However, some scholars think most of genus Homo had language as well, which would essentially push the birth of language back to a time when all of our ancestors were confined to Africa. This would also make it roughly coincident with the earliest stone tools.